# How can I add an extra property to django-rest-framework's ModelSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating my first django API with django-rest-framework.
I have a list of Posts. Each post can have many Likes. Therefore, I have added a ForeignKey to the Like model, which points to its corresponding Post.

When I retrieve the information of a post, I'd like to get the number of likes that this post has.

Here is my url:

```py
path(BASE_URL + "get/slug/<slug:slug>", GetPost.as_view()),
```

This is my view:

```py
class GetPost(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"
```

And this is my serializer:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes_amount = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_likes_amount(self, post):
        return post.likes

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I add the extra property `likes-amount` to the serializer, the API endpoint stops working and I get the following error: Object of type RelatedManager is not JSON serializable.

I'd like to know how I can extend the ModelSerializer with extra fields like the number of likes of my Post, so that I can get. I have read the documentation but haven't found any information on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post.likes` returns a queryset with related models. if you want the count of likes use `count()` on that queryset.

```
def get_likes_amount(self, post):
    return post.likes.count()
```